# Remote debuging with chrome only works with older crosswalk version [cordova 4]

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, crosswalk-runtime

Trying to inspect a `cordova4` app built with crosswalk version `12.41.296.9` ends up in full white chrome window.

The complete same App, built with crosswalk version `10.39.235.15` is fully debuggable with chrome.

I already compared the gradle settings, the properties files and the generated manifests. The only difference is in the file `project.properties`:

- crosswalk v10: target=android-19
- crosswalk v12: target=android-21

Any suggestions why?

**Note**: The crosswalk packages can be found here:

- https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/stable/12.41.296.9/arm/crosswalk-cordova-12.41.296.9-arm.zip
- https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/stable/10.39.235.15/arm/crosswalk-cordova-10.39.235.15-arm.zip

Comment: I have no problem inspecting with Chrome an Ionic project having set crosswalk, version 12.41.296.5, as "browser".

Comment: @beaver: ty for your note! Which minimum API version and android SDK version is your app compiled?

Comment: These are my project versions: android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22"

Comment: @beaver: ty, but it also doesn't work for me with the mentioned crosswalk version above. The target sdk is fixed by the crosswalk version i guess. It's 21.

Comment: I'm a pretty new Crosswalk user, but I've found that my Cordova version affects whether I can use the debugger in VS2015.  When I build for the VS Android Emulator with Cordova v5.3.3, I cannot use the debugger.  When I build with Cordova v6.0.0, I can debug.  Is it possible that the Chrome debugger is dependent on Cordova version, like the VS2015 debugger?

Comment: @pprchsvr: ty for your note. I will try and report it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is compatibility issue of the different versions between cordova and crosswalk.

**Update:**

<strike>With `cordova5` and crosswalk `12.41.296.9` the chrome inspect works as expected.</strike>  => In another app with the same setup it does not work again.